# Use resíduos de regressão para calcular outra regressão (dentro da função) em R

Tags: r, regressão, funções

Eu estou usando uma função para calcular regressões. Eu preciso dos resíduos de uma relação específica para  relacionar a outra variável.
Porém eu preciso que os resíduos sejam calculados de acordo com facet grid.

Assim, para cada uma das divisões os resíduos serão específicos.
Este é meu código, mas ele retorna os valores nulos.

```
reg = function(data) {
    model1 = lm(r ~ a,data= df)
    model1_sum = summary(model1)
    residuals = as.data.frame(model1$residuals)
    df2 = cbind(df,residuals)
    names(df2)[names(df2)=="model1$residuals"] <- "residuals"
    model2 = lm(residuals ~ a,data= df2)
    model2_sum = summary(model2)
    formula = sprintf("y= %.3f %+.3f*x",coef(model)[1], coef(model)[2])
    r = model2_sum$r.squared
    r2 = sprintf("r2= %.3f", r)
    x  = cor.test(~residuals + lat,data = df2)
    r0 = sprintf("r= %.3f", sqrt(model2_sum$r.squared))
    p1 =  pf(model2_sum$fstatistic[1],model2_sum$fstatistic[2],model2_sum$fstatistic[3],lower.tail=F)
    p =sprintf("p = %.3f", p1)
    n0 = length(model2_sum$residual)
    n1 = sprintf("N = %.f", n0)
    data.frame(formula=formula, r=r0,r2=r2, p=p,n=n1, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}

df2_math = ddply(data, c("continente","banco"), df2)
df2_math
```

Comment: Joyce, você poderia postar um exemplo reprodutível dos seus dados? Além disso, seu código parece estar incompleto: em nenhum momento você utiliza a função `reg`, os objetos `df` e `df2` não foram definidos e você não usa o argumento da função dentro dela.

Answer (score 0):

O código tem vários erros. A função produz resultados, mas não sei se o que esta tentando fazer.

```
# simulando dados
set.seed(123)
e=rnorm(50)
a=runif(50,2,6)+2*e;lat=rnorm(50,3,.5)
df=data.frame(r=2+5*a^2+e,a,lat)

reg = function(data) { #data=df
  model1 = lm(r ~ a,data= data)
  model1_sum = summary(model1)
  residuals = as.data.frame(model1$residuals)
  df2 = cbind(data,residuals)
  names(df2)[names(df2)=="model1$residuals"] <- "residuals"
  model2 = lm(residuals ~ a,data= df2)
  model2_sum = summary(model2)
  formula = sprintf("y= %.6g %+.6g*x",coef(model2)[1], coef(model2)[2])
  r = model2_sum$r.squared
  r2 = sprintf("r2= %.4f", r)
  x  = cor.test(~residuals + lat,data = df2)
  r0 = sprintf("r= %.4f", sqrt(model2_sum$r.squared))
  p1 =  pf(model2_sum$fstatistic[1],model2_sum$fstatistic[2],model2_sum$fstatistic[3],lower.tail=F)
  p =sprintf("p = %.4f", p1)
  n0 = length(model2_sum$residual)
  n1 = sprintf("N = %.f", n0)
  data.frame(formula=formula, r=r0,r2=r2, p=p,n=n1, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}
reg(df)

              formula         r         r2          p      n
1 y= -5.0243e-16 +0*x r= 0.0000 r2= 0.0000 p = 1.0000 N = 50
```